# create a new Array with filtered out props

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I have been trying to filter an Array by its props and not by its value so my original array would be -

```
const orignalArray =[
{id: 1, name:"jim", email:"jim@mail.com",age:20},
{id: 1, name:"jom", email:"jom@mail.com",age:30}
]
```

id like to be able to use (n) amount of filters.
My output array would look ideally look like this

```
const filterList["id","age"]
```

```
const newArray=[{name:"jim", email:"jim@mail.com"},{ name:"jom", email:"jom@mail.com"}]
```

I have tried to use filter() but cant seem to get it to work.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: To clarify - are you trying to filter the array by the contained objects' properties (i.e. return users with an age of 30) or are you trying to remove properties of the objects in an array (your result array has all the same objects but with some of their properties removed)?

Comment: Hi I am trying to remove the property completely so the new array would no longer contain them. So in the new array ```newArray.id``` for instance wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you aren't filtering the array rather creating a new one based on the original with derived elements from each. To achieve this you can use the [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to loop over the array and create a new one with new objects without the desired properties, e.g.:

```
function removeArrayElementProps(arr, propsToRemove) {
  return arr.map((element) => {
    // Create a copy of the original element to avoid modifying the original
    const newElement = {...element};

    // Remove the desired properties from the new element
    propsToRemove.forEach((propToRemove) => {
      delete newElement[propToRemove];
    });

    // Returning the modified element in map puts it in thew new arry
    return newElement;
  });
}
```

Then you simply call:

```
const newArr = removeArrayElementProps(orignalArray, ['id','age']);
```

This loops over the array, creates a copy of each element, and removes the specified properties from the element.

Comment: Thankyou this worked perfectly. I didn't know delete existed. I have some reading up to do! I hope your evening is long and peaceful.